# I get an error when I try to display the user details after getting them in onInit() method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'servers' of undefined" when requesting the user details in the onInit() method.

This is the typescript for the page to show the details:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    let response = this.service.getUserDetails();
    response.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data;
    })
  }
```

And this is the getUserDetails method:

```js
public getUserDetails(): Observable<any> {
    let tokenStr = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', tokenStr)
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/user/getdetails', {headers});
  }
```

And this is the HTML:

```html
<ul *ngFor="let server of user.servers">
    <li>Name: {{server.serverName}}</li>
</ul>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you get when you fetch data from `http://localhost:8080/api/user/getdetails` ?

Comment: I get an user object with username, email and other details. The object is there, but i get this error

Comment: Try to add question mark after user. Like this `user?.servers`

Comment: Thanks! It works! Can you explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` pipe in html file.

`*ngFor="let server of user.servers | async as serv"`
Then use `serv.serverName`

This pipe will populate `serv` only when api call subscription is completed.

Comment: Now I get 2 errors. ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe and TypeError: Cannot read property 'servers' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

`user` property is undefined till then the ajax call is completed, and gets initialized in subscription. `user.servers` in template file gives an error in initial stage, where as `user?.servers` will continue to access `.servers` property only when `user` property is defined.